# Zooming the image of particular portion through jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the image of gray scale of 150 dpi. The problem is that I am scanning the document online and saving it to data base the in the `tiff` format and then after I am showing the image the document like form and identity proof in which the font of the row is very small so that after scanning the image not showing very clear. So please guide me what is the possible solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript zooming library. Take a look here

http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/04/introducing-wadda-the-image-zoomer-using-canvas/